# Progessive Group By Command

Tags: sql-server, group-by

This problem arises in many practical situations where missing values are to be replaced with expected values determined from the remaining available values.  I am trying to calculate average of column A over n column, say C1, ..., Cn that can have null values. Whenever one of the columns is null, I would like to replace the calculated average to be over the values present in the other columns and exclude the null column. So for example, if there are just 3 columns (c1, C2, and C3), where ever all three columns have a value I would like to report the average for the subgroups in these three columns.  When one column, say third column, is missing then the average is calculated over values of the other two columns.  If a second column is also missing then the average is calculated over values of one column only.

So one answer is to just report:

```
Select Avg(A) as AvgA
From Table
Group by C1, C2, and C3
```

for the situation where C3 is null and C1 and C2 have the values v1 and v2, then the AvgA should be calculated as:

```
Select Avg(A) as AvgA
From Table 
Where C1=v1 and C2=v2
Group by C1, C2
```

Can anyone give me a code that does this automatically for all n columns?  The general n column solution would need to be able to use n-1 Group By columns and drop one column that is null.  The n-1 Group-By need to be evaluated at v1 through vn-1 values.

Comment: Some sample data and your expected results woot go a long way in helping you.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the 3 columns is null, then it will automatically use the other 2 for the grouping. If 2 of the 3 are null, then the third is used for grouping. If all 3 are null you would get one row in the result where all 3 are null as the grouping.

```
Select c1, c2, c3, Avg(A) as AvgA From Table Group by C1, C2, and C3
```

i.e. From what I understand of your question you just need to group by the  columns.

If a simple approach isn't sufficient, then you could try something like this:

```
Select 
       coalesce(c1,c2,c3) c123
     , coalesce(c2,c3)    c23
     , c3
     , Avg(A) as AvgA
Avg(A) as AvgA From Table 
Group by
       coalesce(c1,c2,c3)
     , coalesce(c2,c3)
     , c3
```